# How to generate multiple files similar to a file kept in one particular location using batch script

Tags: file, batch-file

I want to generate multiple files similar to the one which I have kept it in some particular location.
For example the file name is "MM_MTL_IM_20180726123109", only last two digits of the file name should keep on changing.
Can we achieve this with batch script or please suggest me any other technique

Comment: What do you want to change them to?....a frog!

Comment: last two digit of the file name should go on increment like 00 01 02 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example script which is designed not for efficiency or to be the best method but to show some elementary batch file commands with their syntax in a logical progression.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "FullFileName=MM_MTL_IM_20180726123109.ext"

If Not Exist "%FullFileName%" Exit /B

For %%A In ("%FullFileName%") Do (
    Set "FileNameOnly=%%~nA"
    Set "FileExtension=%%~xA"
)

Set "FileNameBarLastTwoChars=%FileNameOnly:~,-2%"
Set "LastTwoFileNameChars=%FileNameOnly:~-2%"

For /L %%A In (100,1,159) Do (
    Set "Seconds=%%A"
    If Not "%%A"=="1%LastTwoFileNameChars%" (
        Call Copy "%FullFileName%" "%FileNameBarLastTwoChars%%%Seconds:~-2%%%FileExtension%"
    )
)

Pause
```

You only requested 'multiple' files with no explanation, so you will need to make adjustments to the code if you don't wish this script to `copy` your file `59` times so that you have sixty matching files with different names in the same directory, each having valid seconds.
Your question also states 'generate' not `copy`, so you will have to adjust the code if the `copy` assumption was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "name=%~1"
set "stem=%name:~,-2%"
for /L %%i in (10,1,59) do copy %name% %stem%%%i
```

This batchfile takes the original filename as parameter and creates 49 copies of it, appending "10" to "59" instead of the last 2 characters.
In this simple form this will work only if original file and copies are in the same, the current, directory.

Comment: When I replaced name element by my filename, i am getting system cant find the file specified error in command prompt

Comment: I've called my batchfile with "MM_MTL_IM_20180726123109" as parameter, and it went OK. Though for that name not necessary, I've added quotes to allow for blanks within the filename. And you should now see what is going wrong if you change the first line to ECHO ON.